# RaspberyPI high quality camera with opencv on max resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi, opencv, raspberry-pi4, python

I bought [RPI high quality camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/) and trying to make it work it with opencv and python.

I'm using Raspbery PI4 with latest updates (`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`)

Its max resolution is **4056x3040** but it won't works on opencv with resolution more than **2560x1680**.

With `raspistill` it works normally even on **4056x3040**

**I tried next resolutions in opencv:**

- 2048x1536 works
- 2048x1680 works
- 2240x1680 works
- 2560x1440 works
- 2560x1680 and above not works

**raspistill command (works):**

```
raspistill -w 4056 -h 3040
```

**Python example code to work with max resolution (not works):**

```py
import cv2 as cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

HIGH_VALUE = 10000

# (Of cause, I tried to set manually all resolutions in next two lines)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, HIGH_VALUE)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HIGH_VALUE)

width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

print(f"Camera resolution: {width}x{height}") # prints 4056x3040

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        # Here it exit if resolution is 2560x1680 and above
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: cameras have different modes for video and still pictures. still picture modes usually allow higher resolutions, but are unsuitable for video.

Comment: I understand this point, but raspistill displays video with maximum resolution in any case.

Comment: How to configure opencv to use still image mode for rpi camera? May be this can help?

Comment: Try decreasing the frame-rate (fps) first, before increasing the size.

Comment: I already tried. 1fps, 5fps. Not helps.

Comment: I am not using HQ camera but facing similar issues with 5MP infrared pi camera. For me, the camera fails to load for any resolution above 1600, sometimes it even just hangs the script trying to initiate the camera.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the specs of the camera, I think it justifies why you only can record video in the resolutions that you have referred to:

[image]

Note that the only supported video modes are 2028 × 1080p50, 2028 × 1520p40, and 1332 × 990p120.